# jOOQ: DataAccessException and constraints

Tags: java, http, unique-constraint, jooq, http-status-code-400

I am implementing a REST API with Jersey and jOOQ.

I have a table with some constraints, for example a unique key. When inserting a tuple which violates this constraint, jOOQ throws a `DataAccessException`:

```
org.jooq.exception.DataAccessException: SQL [insert into ...]; ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "issue_name_key"
```

Is there a way to find out which constraint has been violated, without string-parsing the error message? If a constraint is violated, I want to return a `400 bad request` http status code instead of a `500 general error`.

If this is not possible, what is common practise here? Should I query the database for each possible constraint violation? This smells like a maintenance trap.

Comment: you can call `e.getCause()` on the JOOQ exception to drill down.

Comment: @assylias That returns only a `PSQLException` without further distinction.

Comment: jOOQ doesn't have anything built in to disambiguate such exceptions - e.g. when JDBC drivers don't make use of all the possible JDBC exceptions. But perhaps, you could use Spring's exception translation mechanism for this?

Comment: I will take a look to Spring's translation!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per comment by Lukas Eder: not possible in jOOQ, since it only relies on JDBC exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure jOOQ DataAccessException supports the 'contains' method .But with "org.springframework.dao.DataAccessException" , we can implement in the following way.

```
import org.springframework.dao.DataAccessException;
import org.springframework.dao.DuplicateKeyException;

    catch(DataAccessException sqlExcep) {
                if(sqlExcep.contains(DuplicateKeyException.class)) {
    System.out.println("Duplicate key exception found. Return 400 bad request ");
    }
    else {
    System.out.println("Some other  exception. Return 500 bad request ");
    }
    }
```